# Calling VoiceCommandDefinitionManager Causes Thread Execution to Stop

Tags: voice, windows-10, cortana, uwp

I'm totally at a loss. When I call either:

```
var a = VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstalledCommandDefinitions;
```

OR

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager
    .InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync( storageFile );
```

Execution of the thread ends inside either call.

For example, in the following method after calling InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFilesAsync nothing happens. No exception, no write lines, no execution after calling that method.

```
private async void RegisterVoiceCommands()
{
    var storageFile =
        await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync( new Uri( "ms-appx:///VoiceCommandDefinition.xml" ) );
    try
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync( storageFile );

        Debug.WriteLine( "Voice Commands Registered" );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( ex );
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This used to work in the Technical Preview.

ENVIRONMENT:
Win 10 Enterprise
VS2015 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out in my case it's a machine issue. The project works correctly on every other box I tried it on. Bad install I guess.